# HTTP requests being blocked by a previous one using Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, http, alamofire, charles-proxy

I'm having some trouble with an HTTP request performed from our iOS app to our API. The problem with this request is that it usually takes 30-40s to complete. I don't need to handle the response for now, so I just need to fire it and forget about it. **I don't know if the problem is in my code or in the server, that's why I'm asking here.**

I'm using **Alamofire** and **Swift 2.2** and all the other requests are working just fine. This is an screenshot from **Charles proxy** while I was trying to debug it: [Charles screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uco8J.png)

As you can see, the request that blocks the others is the `refreshchannels`. When that request fires (**#6** and **#25**), the others are blocked and don't finish until the `refreshchannels` finishes.

Here is the code that triggers that request and also the APIManager that i've built on top of Alamofire:

```
// This is the method that gets called when the user enables the notifications in the AppDelegate class
func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
    // Recieve the APNSToken and handle it. I've removed it to make it shorter

    // This sends a POST to our API to store some data
    APIManager().registerForPushNotifications(parametersPush) { (result) in
        switch result {
        case .Success (let JSON):
            // This is the slow call that blocks the other HTTP requests
            APIManager().refreshChannels { _ in } // I don't need to handle the response for now
        case .Failure: break
        }
    }
}
```

And the manager:

```
//This is my custom manager to handle all the networking inside my app
class APIManager {

    typealias CompletionHandlerType = (Result) -> Void

    enum Result {
        case Success(AnyObject?)
        case Failure(NSError)
    }

    let API_HEADERS = Helper.sharedInstance.getApiHeaders()
    let API_DOMAIN = Helper.sharedInstance.getAPIDomain()

    //MARK: Default response to a request
    func defaultBehaviourForRequestResponse(response: Response<AnyObject, NSError>, completion: CompletionHandlerType) {
        print("Time for the request \(response.request!.URL!): \(response.timeline.totalDuration) seconds.")
        switch response.result {
        case .Success (let JSON):
            if let _ = JSON["error"]! {
                let error = NSError(domain: "APIError", code: response.response!.statusCode, userInfo: JSON as? [NSObject : AnyObject])
                completion(Result.Failure(error))
            } else {
                completion(Result.Success(JSON))
            }
        case .Failure (let error):
            completion(Result.Failure(error))
        }
    }

    func refreshChannels(completion: CompletionHandlerType) {
        Alamofire.request(.PUT, "\(API_DOMAIN)v1/user/refreshchannels", headers: API_HEADERS).responseJSON { response in
            self.defaultBehaviourForRequestResponse(response, completion: completion)
        }    
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated. Have a nice day!